# Getting error on converting list of string into a list with separate integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have  a list of type string li=['192 245 3 881250949']

if i print li it shows

```
'196\t242\t3\t881250949'
```

How do i obtain the list li in the form of separate integers

`li=[192 245 3 881250949]` i.e list of integers

I am getting error on using map

```
results = list(map(int, li))
```

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
>   '196\t242\t3\t881250949'

Can someone explain this and help to transform the list ?

Comment: kindly dont close this mods i am stuck for 2 hours now ..

Comment: `lst = [int(i) for i in '196\t242\t3\t881250949'.split()]` using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: since this is big list of lists i need to use something like li.split()  instead of '196\t242\t3\t881250949'.split() as this line is under loop can you specify in term of li?

Comment: not sure i understand your question... but `split` is a member of `str`- so you just apply it to your strings (inside your nested list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `ValueError` because `int()` can't convert a string which contains non-digit characters. Here, the string contains `'\t'`, so raising the error.

A simple way to convert it into list of integers will be to do this(the string contains numbers separated by `'\t'` then use `'\t'` instead of `' '` inside `split()`):

```
lst = list(map(int, li[0].split(' ')))
```

If you have more than one such string in the list `li`, then you can use a loop to do the job. Let me know if I am able to answer your query.

Comment: thanks bro it worked except that i needed to change it to li[0].split(' \t ') i/o li[0].split(' ')

Comment: It's my pleasure to be helpful for you :) Any question you have in mind?

Comment: hey kindly change it to li[0].split(' \t ')  to make it more accurate //

Comment: Which version of Python do you use? Actually, in 3.6 it's not showing `'196\t242\t3\t881250949'`, instead showing `'196 242 3 881250949'`. If the string contains `'\t'` then use `split('\t')`.

Comment: oh ok  its 3.something in my system  you might be correct when i was using li[0].split(' ') it was throwing error so i changed it to li[0].split('\t')  which was giving correct output  coz even if i print li it shows '196\t242\t3\t881250949' . anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested list comprehension:

```
l=[int(el) for s in li for el in s.split()]
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[192, 245, 3, 881250949]
```

Answer (score 1):

this code can help you.
first you must split the string with `split()`

then you can use `map` or `for loop` for convert string to int

```
# with map

li=['192 245 3 881250949']
a=li[0].split(' ')

a = list(map(int,a))


# with for loop

li=['192 245 3 881250949']
a=li[0].split(' ')

for i in range (len(a)):
    a[i] = int(a[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li=['192 245 3 881250949']

print(li)
```